# Nighwatch - multiple basic auth

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, nightwatch.js

I have situation like this: I'm logging to stage http server which is secured by basic auth. I'm running my test with url combined with basic auth credentials `url("http://mylogin:mypass@mywebsite.com")`

Then I'm going to website login page and backend server switches protocol to https, showing new basic auth window.

Any ideas how to handle it in Nightwatch? How to handle multiple basic auth alerts?

Comment: the easiest way would be to open your site using `https` instead of `http` (`url("http://mylogin:mypass@mywebsite.com")`)

Comment: @nirmus Yes. It works at login page, where https is. But after logging process, server switches back to http, showing basic auth. So I have situation like this https on login and register page and http on rest of the site.

Comment: this is weird server configuration. Why not to fix your server config and not switch you back to `http` once you log in using `https`?